# How would I check if the last 8 characters in an input are numbers and are not zero using else if statements? Java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am trying to build a program to calculate grades. Part of that requires entering a student ID in the correct format (A########). The errors I'm testing for are: Is the input "quit"?, Is the first character 'A'?, Is the total length 9 characters?, Are the last 8 characters digits?, and Are the last 8 digits not 0. I figured out the first three but I can't figure out how to check the last two criteria. I also need to include NumberFormatException. My code is not currently functional but this is what I have so far:

```
public static String getStudentID(String sid) {
      boolean goodval = false;
      long snum = Long.parseLong(sid.substring(1));
        
      do{
          try{
              if (sid.equals("quit")) {
                  goodval = true;
              } else if (sid.charAt(0) != 'A') {
                  System.out.println("Student ID must start with 'A'");
                  goodval = false;
              } else if (sid.length()!=9) {
                  System.out.println("Student ID must be 9 characters long");
                  goodval = false;
              } else if (Long.parseLong(sid.substring(1))) {
                  goodval = false;
              } else {
                  goodval = true;
              }
    
          } catch (NumberFormatException e){ 
            System.out.println("The last part of the ID" + sid.substring(1) + " was not a number.");
            sc.nextLine();
          }
      } while (goodval = false);
      return sid;
   }
```

Comment: So you would need to iterate over the last 8 characters and test each one to check that it is a digit; e.g. a character in the range `'0'` to `'9'`.  Is that enough for you to work it out?

Comment: The last 8 digits can’t all be 0, but the rest holds, an iteration would work or, substring from position 1 to8 and if it converts to an int > 1 it’s valid

Comment: The OP already has a test for that.  Albeit a broken one.  `parseLong` doesn't return a `boolean` ... so the test needs to compare the result with .... something :-).

Comment: Explain if you will, how you're required to include NumberFormatException. Do you have to test the entire string or some specific part of it for the exception?

Answer (score 0):

This regex should hit all requirements in one line
:
[A]{1}\d{8}(?<!A00000000)|quit

Test it here: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5bA%5d%7b1%7d%5cd%7b8%7d%28%3f%3c!A00000000%29%7cquit&i=A12345678

Comment: I think the OP wants to do it using `if` statements.  At least, that is what the Question title says.

Comment: Yeah, just a more succinct alternative imho in case op did not consider regular expression albeit it won’t provide as granular validation output..

Answer (score 0):

The `String` class has a method call `length()`, which returns an integer representing the number of characters in the String. The last eight characters of a String would be indexed `length() - 1` through `length() - 8`.

The Character class has a static method of interest, [isDigit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)), which returns `true` if a character is a digit.

I'm not sure how you want to structure your code, but here's an example that will break down the alternatives for you.

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < sid.length(); counter++)
{
    if(Character.isDigit(sid.charAt(counter))
    {
        if(sid.charAt(counter) == '0')
        {
            // it's a digit AND it's a zero
        }
        else
        {
            // it's a digit, but not a zero
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // it's alpha or whitespace
    }
}
```